# RestSharp: How to custom-deserialize from the response stream?

Tags: json.net, deserialization, restsharp

I'm implementing a custom deserializer for RestSharp using Json.NET.  On Json.NET's documentation's [Performance Tips](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) page, it recommends deserializing from a stream to avoid large JSON strings ending up in the large object heap.  However, RestSharp's IDeserializer.Deserialize() method accepts an IRestResponse, which appears to only allow access to the response content via string property.  How can I access the response stream in my custom deserializer?